# MATLAB error - Undefined function "imrotate" for input arguments of type 'int16'

Tags: matlab, undefined, uint16

I don't know what's going on. I need some advice or resolution for this problem

The following code is:

```
ax_slice = reshape(im(:,:,slices/2),rows,cols);
sag_slice = reshape(im(:,cols/2,:),rows,slices);
cor_slice = reshape(im(rows/2,:,:),cols,slices);
figure;
subplot(2,2,1);imshow(ax_slice,[]);
ax_slice_rot = imrotate(ax_slice,180);
subplot(2,2,1);imshow(ax_slice_rot,[]);
subplot(2,2,2);imshow(sag_slice,[]);
sag_slice_rot = imrotate(sag_slice,90);
imshow(sag_slice_rot,[]);
subplot(2,2,3);imshow(cor_slice,[]);
cor_slice_rot = imrotate(cor_slice,90);
imshow(cor_slice_rot,[]);
```

The error displayed like this:

```
Undefined function 'imrotate' for input arguments of type 'int16'.

Error in lab0_introduction (line 19)
ax_slice_rot = imrotate(ax_slice,180);
```

Thank you very much

Comment: It's part of the [Image processing toolbox](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrotate.html). EIther you don't have that one installed or created a variable which is called `imrotate`

Comment: To check whether such toolbox is installed, type `ver` in the Command Window. A few infos regarding your Matlab installation will pop up, along with the list of all the toolbox installed.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, this is typically because you don't have the [Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/functionlist.html) installed. The *easiest* way to check this is to type the following:

```
 which('imrotate')
```

If the result is this statement

> imrotate is a variable.

Then that means that you've accidentally given a variable that name so MATLAB can't locate the true function. To fix this, you will want to run the following.

```
clear imrotate
```

If, however, the result of the `which` command is

> 'imrotate' is not found

This means that you don't have the image processing toolbox installed on your current system.